# How do I say "WWI" out loud?

Tags: pronunciation, abbreviations

I know it's written WWI, but when I am speaking should I say "World War One" or "World War First" or "First World War"?

Comment: "The Great War."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've always heard people referring to it either as "World War One" or "the first World War". I guess the second is slightly more "formal".

Answer (score 6):

Looking for what the *Corpus of Contemporary American* reports, I get the [following data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fj3QB.png).

[image]

Comment: No, you don't have two mouse cursors all in a sudden. My mouse cursor just wanted to appear in the screenshot.

Comment: Photobombed by a cursor; that just made my day.

Comment: The proper pronunciation is "dubaya dubaya one."

Answer (score 2):

World War II is almost always said "World War Two", so by convention, World War I follows: "World War One".
As an interesting aside, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_I) notes:

> The terms World War I and First World War both became standard (in the United States and Britain respectively) beginning in about 1940 to 1942; prior to that, it was most commonly called The Great War.

Comment: As clearly demonstrated by this [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Great+War%2CWorld+War+I%2CFirst+World+War&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

Answer (score 2):

I have not heard "The Great War" outside of historical fiction. I have heard "the first world war," but not nearly as often as "World War One." In fact, I hear people say "double-u double-u one" about as often as "the first world war," if not in the same conversation/paper.

Comment: That's odd.  I can safely say I've never heard people say "double-u double-u one."

Comment: ...In informal settings, I hear people go back and forth between what sound like "dubya dubya one" (or "dubloo...") and "were were one." It could just be something local. I've always taken it for granted. Who knows?

Comment: "The Great War" is largely a European usage. The term has fallen out of use since WW2.

Comment: I have also heard w-w-one but I don't really suggest it as it takes longer to say than World War One and sounds funny.

Comment: @MrHen: Sounds funny to YOU, mayhaps! :) Not disagreeing, though. World War One, or as we say "were were one" is definitely more common, easier to say, and alliterative to boot! "w-w-one" is still an option, though, and, IMHO, shouldn't be given short shrift because of whatever perceived inferiorities. In some cases, I prefer saying "w-w-one" to "world war one"... but that's just my personal preference.

Comment: @kitukwfyer This striking [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Great+War%2Cgreat+war%2CWorld+War+One%2Cworld+war+one%2CFirst+World+War%2Cfirst+world+war&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) is about printed books rather than pronunciation, but shows a peak of *Great War/great war* around 1920, *First World War* picking up around 1937 and surpassing *Great War* in 1941. *World War One* is negligible by comparison.

Answer (score 1):

*WWI* is an abbreviation for "World War One."  You could alternatively say "the First World War" or "The Great War" (though that has been rare since WWII), but I would normally expect to see either of those versions written out in full.  If the text says "WWI", reading out "the First World War" would not be reading what was written, though it might be a perfectly reasonable thing to do depending on the circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

The three ways to refer to WWI are:

> World War One
>
> The First World War
>
> The Great War

"World War One" is easily the most common. The second is complete misnomer considering the world wars that happened before World War I. The Great War is what WWI was referred to before WWII.

I suggest using "World War One" unless you want to show off your history skills by referring to "The Great War."

Comment: How is the second a misnomer and the first not?

Comment: @nico: It still sort of is, but the other world wars were not numbered. "First" is implying "this was the first world war." "World War I" strictly means "this World War has the number of I".

Comment: @MrHen: Just out of curiosity, which other wars would you consider to be world wars?

Comment: @oosterwal: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_war#Earlier_worldwide_conflicts) has a good list. The best examples would be the Napoleonic Wars and the Seven Years' War.

Comment: Maybe we haven't really had a *World* War at all yet. I don't recall South America being much involved in the main contenders for the title thus far.

Comment: @Fumble: Did you look at the Wiki link? It has color coded maps showing participants; five of the examples have S. America listed in varying degrees.

Comment: @MrHen: those were major wars that spilled out of Europe as such, but surely just between the European powers?  Aside from Alexander the Great's conquest of large chunks of everywhere, I can't think of anything that really counts.  Even WWI is pushing it -- the Americans arrived on the scene rather late, and the ANZACs and similar units belonged to the European powers really.

Comment: Duh.  I can't believe I forgot the Mongols.

Comment: @Rhodri: Hey, feel free to define a "world war" however you want. I am simply pointing to what little I know about history and wars and providing a(n albeit weak) reference.

Comment: @MrHen: "complete misnomer" is quite a strong statement, so I reckon it's only fair to challenge it.

Comment: @Rhodri: Fair enough. WWI and WWII seem to be the most obvious world wars and are arguably the greatest/largest of them. I don't have a problem replacing "complete" with "a likely" if that softens the statement enough.

Comment: Note that "The Great War" doesn't definitively refer to World War I either, at least in Europe. Prior to WWI, it was used to refer to the Napoleonic Wars.